# How is App server rate calculated in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

The [Monitoring MarkLogic guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/history#id_pgfId-1114363) says:

> **Request Rate**  The number of queries being processed per second by each App Server.

Does an XQuery mean 1 query or an XQuery will have many queries?

What does query mean to MarkLogic and how can we calculate the number of queries in an XQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "query" in this context refers to what may more commonly be called a request.

Let's say you load a custom resource at `/v1/resources/my-resource`, and my-resource calls `cts.search` 5 times. If you send 100 requests to `/v1/resources/my-resource`, that would equal 100 "queries". It would not be 500 queries - i.e. each individual `cts.search/cts.uris/cts.elementValues/`, etc. does not count as a separate query.

Comment: So if I'm sending a http request that fetches 100 documents? The toal request will still be 1 or 100?

Comment: That is one request

Answer (score 0):

"Request Rate" is the rate of 'requests'.  A 'Request' in an App (http) server is a single (attempted) HTTP request (GET, PUT etc)
This is most often also a single transaction/'query' 
The docs made more sense in earlier versions of ML before the client API's existed the connection between a user 'request' and the server 'query' was more obvious.